# How to implement a named Pipe in C++ on Mac OS?

Tags: java, c++, macos, pipe, ipc

I am working on a c++ program that I want to communicate with a Java program(JAR file).

C++ will write into the pipe and the Java side will read out from the pipe. I have already implemented this functionality in Windows. Please don't recommend alternate ways on how I can communicate between these two programs; I have explored and tested a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: [man 2 mkfifo](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mkfifo.2.html)

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to write to `std::out` from the c++ programm and read from `std::in` in the java programm. You create the pipe with `mkfifo`, then start your cpp programm and redirect its output to the pipe and after that start your java programm and redirect its input to the pipe.

The the calls look something like this

```
mkfifo myPipe
./cppProgramm > myPipe&
java javaProgramm < myPipe&
```